# Oracle: Replace corrupted first datafile

Tags: oracle

A datafile associated with a tablespace has been corrupted (got truncated to size 0). I don't mind losing the data, because I have a full DB dump which I can import. Now I want to replace this datafile, or provide this tablespace with a new datafile so that the corrupted one can be ignored.

I cannot drop the tablespace because it is spread over multiple partitions. I cannot bring this corrupted file online because it throws an IO error when doing so.

So the only option is : replace this datafile, or add a new one.

If I just add a new datafile, will this new datafile be used and the corrupted one be left alone?

**Update:** A coworker suggested that I add a new datafile and edit the 'pfile' to point to the new datafile.
Can this work?

Comment: datafiles are adminstered in the controlfile, not in the [s]pfile. Is the db running archivelog mode and do you have a backup?

Comment: @ik_zelf I dropped the user, then I was able to drop the tablespaces. Now I'm recreating the user and the tablespaces at a new location, and then i'll import all the  data of which I had taken a dump just yesterday (thankfully)

Comment: Dropping the tablespace is the really the quickest solution, especially if not only the data segments but also the headers of the datafile are corrupt.

Comment: Oops it was asked long back. just like to add my views to it Just to know, You mentioned that you have full DB Dump. Does it RMAN backup? If yes and your database is running in archivelog mode then you can restore that particular datafile to the state of backup time or before the time of datafile corruption by recovering database using available archivelogs.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the datafile has been occupied by a partition of a table, you need to ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION with some empty dummy table. Then drop the exchanged table. Then rebuild the invalidated indexes. This works if you don't have foreign keys to the table. This is quite a troublesome operation. Then you are free to drop the corrupted datafile.

Comment: Hey, a coworker suggested that I add a new datafile and edit the pfile to point to the new datafile. So the corrupted one just stays there ignored forever. Will that work?

Comment: Of course not...